# Elixir ex_aws AWS S3 Delete Object Returns 403 Access Deined

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions, elixir, amazon-iam

I'm using the [ex_aws](https://hex.pm/packages/ex_aws) library in Elixir to attempt to delete an
object in an S3 bucket, however, I'm getting a 403, Access Denied
response in production and I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.
As a related issue, using a different bucket and environment, I'm getting a 204 response, but the objects are not *actually* deleted.

The bucket's policy object has the requisite permissions, e.g.:

```
{
    "Sid": "BucketACL",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "${my-apps-arn}"
    },
    "Action": "*",
    "Resource": "${my-buckets-arn}/*"
}
```

I have even tried adding an extra bucket ACL statement that explicitly
adds the `s3:DeleteObject` action, and allows it.

The bucket is not versioned, so I don't think that means I need to add
calls to `DeleteObjectVersion` or similar.

Any help or suggestions to put me in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

It may also be worth mentioning, the `my-apps-arn` is a separate IAM user for the application with an inline policy similar to:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "${my-bucket-arn}",
                "${my-bucket-arn}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

** Edit 2 **

Some more information, the following code is how I'm making the
request:

```
:app_name
|> Application.get_env(:aws_bucket_name)
|> S3.delete_object(path)
|> ExAws.request()
```

Where `path` is set to the object to be deleted.

The relevant EX_AWS configuration variables are set as follows:

```
config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: ["${aws_key_id}"],
  secret_access_key: ["${aws_secret_key}"],
  s3: [
    host: "${s3-bucket-url}",
    region: "${region}"
  ]
```

Furthermore, as an out-of-band suggestion, I've tried to delete an
object with the same credentials through the AWS CLI tool and was in
fact capable of deleting the object. So it may be a client issue after
all.

Comment: Could be many things. When you say the principal is your apps-arn, what do you mean by that? Is that an IAM role, or an IAM user? Or your AWS account ARN? If its an IAM role, I suspect the role isn't attached to your instance.

Comment: @user602525: The `my-apps-arn` is a separate IAM user for the application. The Elixir application is given an access key and secret, so it should not be, as I understand it, an issue of the/a role not being attached to the instance. The user is also given an inline policy that gives it access to the bucket.

Comment: Are you able to delete with curl?

Comment: Did you try access OS variables with `System.get_env/1`?

Comment: @PatNowak: I'm not sure how accessing the variables from `System.get_env/1` would change anything.  To be clear, the notation above is just an informal way to denote that I'm replacing the _actual_ values for security and anonymizing the source, the code uses the values pretty directly.

Comment: @AndyGaskell: I will give it a try, although, if I can, I do suspect it's an issue with the AWS auth signing that happens in `ex_aws`... I'll write back when I've given this a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since switched to using [aws_auth](https://github.com/bryanjos/aws_auth) instead, which is correctly signing the requests for me and allowing me to delete objects in S3.  It may be that there is a bug in [ex_aws](https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws), or more likely, I was attempting to use it incorrectly.  However, using `aws_auth` is both easier, and more supports the workflow of the application, I will be sticking with it.